# Permission to second hard drive? Denied!

Tags: permissions

On a PC running windows, I installed a second hard drive.

Since then I have removed windows and installed elementary OS.

When I go into the file manager hard drive 1, with the OS on, is recognised and all is well. When I try to open hard drive 2, I receive the message  'permission denied'

How do I unlock the access to my second drive?

Answer (score 1):

you will need to mount the drive, elementary os does not auto mount drives like windows.

to mount the drive try

```
sudo mount -o ro /dev/sdb(assumptive it's sdb) /home/[YOUR USER]/desktop
```

this will mount it to your desktop folder that in elementary seems to be empty 90% of the time

then `cd ~/desktop & ls`

this should work assuming this drive is in good health and not damaged in any way

Comment: I successfully mounted the drive but all the files were locked. message: read only ?